# Why does my code produce a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int **a;
    int b[5] = {3,4,5,6,1};
    *a=b;
    cout << *((*a)+0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

According to my understanding `*((*a)+0)` is equivalent to `(*a)[0]`. Am I wrong? How can I make the above code print the first element of the array?

And why does *this* code work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int *a;
    int b[5] = {3,4,5,6,1};
    a=b;
    cout << *(a+0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I replace `a` with `*a` everywhere, why is it wrong?

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `a`.

Comment: You're assigning *pointer to int* to `a` which is a `pointer` to `pointer to int`. So you've to allocate memory for *pointer* to `pointer to int`.

Comment: Look at it this way: `int *a` can be seen as `(no_adr_ptr)a` which changes to `(adr_of_b)a` when you do `a=b`; `int **a` becomes `(no_adr_ptr(no_adr_ptr)a)` and when you do `*a=b` it becomes `(no_adr_ptr(adr_of_b)a)`. hth

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You access an uninitialized pointer in

```
*a=b;
```

At this point `a` points to a random location, and as is the rule with *undefined behavior* you can't predict what will happen. For you it seems to be a location that you can't write to, and so you get a crash.

---

The second variant works because then you make `a` point to `b`, you don't write to an uninitialized pointer, you actually *initialize* the pointer with the location of the first item in `b`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an online reference where I can read and understand perfectly?

Comment: @Alex Sorry but unfortunately I don't know any good pointer tutorials.

Comment: Stroustrup. Pages 1 to 1600 or so.